# Unauthorized access trying to save .rtf file

Tags: c#

I'm having an issue in saving an rtf file, I'm saving it in a subfolder in "MyDocuments" the strange this is that i also save a .bin file and some other stuff and it doesn't causes any exeption, i'am pc admin so why does it happen?

```
string docs = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\Monitor\\Immobili\\";`
```

`richTextBox1.SaveFile(docs+code);`

code is also another string

Comment: Your application doesn't have administrator privileges. You need to run VS as administrator because when debugging your application, it inherits the permissions of VS.

Comment: Probably file is open by other application or another instance of your application.

Comment: That's the file creation from a richTextBox so it's unlikely that file is open

Comment: i both tried to run vs and realise application as administrator but it did not work

Comment: What is the actual exception? Perhaps if you posted the exception.ToString() in your question. "unauthorized acccess" seems a bit vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `UnauthorizedAccessException` means one of 3 things:

- The caller does not have the required permission.
- Path is a directory.
- Path specified a read-only file.

Check for last two reasons. I think you are not adding filename after path. Add breakpoints and check if `richTextBox1.SaveFile(docs+code);` is getting the complete path to the file instead of just folder path.